# Convert php code to native android application?

Tags: php, android, native

I am familiar with phonegap framework which convert html & jquery code to native app. But it does not support php. So i am looking for alternative.

Comment: PHP i unfit for this purpose. But everything you could do on a phone with PHP running locally you can also do with Javascript

Comment: @dtech you mean using javascript php library

Comment: What do you mean with "Javascript PHP library"? There is no such thing. I meant that every thing your code can accomplish in PHP on a phone can also be done with languages that are much better integrated in Android, e.g. Javascript or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language while jQuery and html being client side. What I mean is this that the PHP script is being interpreted on the server using the PHP plugin and compiler and so if it has to run on phone it need to be compiled in the phone with the required plugins.

Seems impossible to now because of that the PHP compiler is not available for android and for making such you should be able to port it to android.

Which I think takes a lot of time and digging the PHP compiler sources.

Answer (score 2):

with Zend Studio 10 you can make your app using PHP
Cloud Connected Mobile app is new entry for PHP Developers to make native apps(android, blackberry, windows phone) with just SINGLE click.

[Zend CCM link](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/cloud_connect_mobile.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In my personal view, do not use a language designed specifically for web server-side purposes on a web client. Everything you can do with PHP locally on a phone you can also do with Javascript, and usually much easier because of its tight integration with the browser.

That said, there is a [PHP for Android](http://www.phpforandroid.net/) project which might provide what you want.

Comment: Yes it is good one, but how to publish a Android app using PHP for Android?